# Deprecated: mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

Running Xlint:deprecated in android studio on my (java) application tells me that

```
   mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
```

is deprecated!

What should I do?

Comment: As per the documentation, you need to pass a `Context` to the constructor.

Comment: Oh, OK, but which documentation are you looking at. I am looking at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder and can't see that.

Comment: Oh ok I see - sorry I was only looking at the top of the page with the example. It does actually say so lower down. It would be nice if they updated the examples! But then again, I should have read it properly.

Answer (score 6):

As commented, MediaRecorder() is replaced by MediaRecorder(Context context). See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#summary but, as of 2022, ignore the example at the top of the page.